# How to use svmtrain

Tags: libsvm

I'm trying to use SVMtrain in matlab for a two class classification problem.
I know that SVMtrain's output is a model with some fields 'rho','nr_class', etc.
Now I want to plot my classifier as a line. How should I do that? How should I incorporate these fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can graph the separating hyperplane using SVM TOY, which comes with LIBSVM. You can find out more about it at the [LIBSVM website](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/svmtoy3d/)